# How would I iterate through a matrix using vector.begin() and vector.end()?

Tags: c++, matrix

I know this is not practical and I could always use .size() or auto& col: matrix, however how would you iterate through a matrix using the following method:

```
   for (std::vector<vector<int>>::iterator col = matrix.begin(); col != matrix.end(); ++col){
       for (std::vector<int>::iterator row = matrix[col].begin(); row != matrix[col].end(); row++){
          std::cout << matrix[col][row] << std::endl;
   }
}
```

I decided this was an awful idea, but wanted to find some way to work through a 2d vector. However, if you can figure this out that would be cool.

Comment: That's definitely not how you use iterators. What resource are you using for learning C++?

Comment: Don't use vectors of vectors as matrices. A matrix is a *rectangular* block of stuff, not some list of lists.

Comment: @Baum A vector of vectors (pre-sized) is a reasonable approximation of a matrix for many purposes, though certainly not for performance-heavy ones.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I would disagree. About the only thing a matrix and the nested vectors have in common is double indexing. Other than that, the semantics are just off.

Comment: @Baum Apart from indexing, which semantics are you thinking of?

Comment: @NeilButterworth `vecOfVecs[0].push_back(7);` makes perfect sense, for starters. `someMatrix[0].push_back(7);` not so much.

Comment: @NeilButterworth A single vector with `index = y * max_x + x` for access is far more performant. It also has the benefit of having a contiguous c-array.

Comment: @Fibbles Yes, I I were writing a matrix class that is what I would do. If I want a quick off-the shelf matrix, I would use a vector of vectors.

Comment: @Neilbutterworth I would say writing 2 small functions for coords to index and vice-versa is a quick solution but to each their own.

Comment: I suppose that would make sense in "competitive programming". If the code is meant to be useful, I'd rather take the time to get some proper matrix type. Probably from some off-the-shelve library.

Comment: there are all kinds of ways to traverse a matrix, row by row, col by col, diagonally etc. to have a traversal you need to define the order. which means you need to map your 2d structure to 1d, so once you defined that, you may  just use a single vector as a matrix.

Comment: I understand that `iterator`s are (quite) new and fancy and cool and totally meta and probably work with every kind of container that will become standard in C++3x. But if I use a `std::vector` (for something like an array with size defined at runtime), why exactly I need `iterator`s? What's wrong with indices and `operator[]`? (Even my colleague can read such expressions although he's writing PHP and JavaScript all days.) (I'm afraid this became a bit emotional...) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;

for (auto col = matrix.begin(); col != matrix.end(); ++col)
    for (auto el = col->begin(); el != col->end(); ++el)
        std::cout << *el << std::endl;
```

Comment: @Captain No, op is trying to use iterators with the subscript operator.

Comment: @Captain No, it isn't. What the OP is currently doing won't compile.

Comment: Sorry, I am not trying to iterate like that. But thank you